# How to solve this sparse matrix effectively?

Tags: matrix-equations, symmetry, symmetric-matrices

I have the following equation:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
K_{mm}&K_{mn}&-I\\
K_{nm}&K_{nn}&0\\
V_C&0&I_C\\
\end{array}
\right]\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_m\\
x_n\\
i_m\\
\end{array}
\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
b_c\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

where $m$ is about several hundred, $n$ is about several million, $I_{m*m}$ is unit matrix and $V_C$, $I_C$ are square matrix with $m*m$, $K_{nn}$ is symmetric sparse matrix and we can get 
$$ K_{nn}=L'L$$
and  $L$ is the lower triangular matrix by Cholesky decomposition,
$$V_C=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&...&-1\\
0&1&...&-1\\
...&...&...&...\\
0&...&1&-1\\
0&0&...&0\\
\end{array}
\right]$$
$$I_C=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&...&0\\
...&...&...\\
0&...&0\\
1&...&1
\end{array}
\right]$$

Is there any efficient method to solve this sparse matrix by $L$?

Thanks,

Tang Laoya

Comment: what do you mean "solve it by $L$"?

Comment: it's the lower triangular matrix by Cholesky decomposition, thanks

Comment: so we can assume we have access to $L$, that it is already computed, or what does it mean?

Comment: yes, it is already computed, but we only access it by $y=L^{-1}x$.

Comment: Ok, but $L^{-1}$ is rather cheap once it is triangular. Just $n^2/2$ multiply-adds for $n\times n$ matrix. $L$ does not happen to be sparse also in excess to being triangular?

Comment: Yes. So do you have any good idea to solve the original system by $L$? Thanks.

Comment: No, usually $L$ is not sparse. In fact, the $K$ matrix is from finite element equations.

Comment: Currently I have to decomposition the whole unsymmetric matrix which will occupy large amount of memory, if I can make use of $L$, we can save almost half memory usage.

Comment: If memory requirements for inversion is the issue then maybe an iterative scheme like Krylov subspace methods could be better. They only require storing 2 or 3 candidate right hand side vectors and no matrix manipulation.

Comment: No, the iterative method is too slow. I have compared the iterative method and direct method if memory is available.

Comment: Is $I_C$ identity or general $m\times m$?

Comment: $I_C$ is a special matrix with all first $m-1$ lines 0 and the last line all 1.

Comment: Ok. If $K_{nn}$ is sparse, is it sure that we gain anything from using $L$ in $L^TL=K_{nn}$? If $K_{nn}$ is mostly $0$s the stuff on the right and down is mostly $0$s and $n>>m$, then the whole matrix is mostly $0$s.

Comment: Yes, the whole matrix is also sparse. On the right, the $b_m$ and $b_n$ are all zeros and only $b_c$ has some non-zero elements.

Comment: Maybe if you add the information in the comments to the question it will get more attention.

Comment: Thanks for your remind. I have updated the original question.